# Qual a maneira correta de se estruturar endereços no MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, banco-de-dados

Quando aprendi SQL, a forma como se estruturava endereço era criar uma série de tabelas (bairros, cidades, estados, paises). Então relacionava as tabelas. Então bastava adicionar somente o id do bairro ao registro em questão(cliente, fornecedor, colaborador...) e o resto era na base do "inner join".
Agora, comecei a usar o MongoDB. É possível obter resultado semelhante  com várias coleções, analogamente ao SQL no MongoDB, executando uma série de *callbacks* no *find*.

Esta é uma prática recomendável, ou devo adicionar todos os campos direto no registro, ou existe algum outro procedimento melhor?

Comment: Remova a tag node.js da sua pergunta, sua dúvida não há relação com essa tecnologia.

Comment: Por que não há relação com essa tecnologia? Não pode existir algo relacionado a ela pelo qual minha prática não é recomendável, como gargalo no servidor, ou outra coisa. Tá bom eu removi a tag.

Answer (score 2):

Eu acredito que não haja resposta correta nem em RDBMS (SQL) ou NoSQL. O design dos dados sempre irá depender do objetivo do seu sistema.

Se você está desenvolvendo algo que cataloga entidades geográficas (cidades, ruas, bairros) tipo Google Maps ou algum serviço de entregas, então pode fazer sentido ultra-normalizar até o nível de logradouro e quarteirão.

Por outro lado, se você está apenas coletando endereços de clientes, e apenas precisa de um único endereço, tipo *Endereço de Cobranças*, seria muito mais simples colocar os campos *endereco*, *bairro*, *cidade*, *UF*, *pais* na própria tabela do cliente.

Da mesma forma é no mongo. Você pode armazenar coleções de cidades, bairros, etc (ex: um bairro `{_id:1, nome: 'Centro', cep: '12345-123', id_cidade: 123}`) e fazer referência em outra coleção (ex: cliente `{_id: 456, nome: 'Restaurante da Praça', endereco: {rua: 'Av Tancredo Neves, 333, sala 14', id_bairro: 1} }`). Ou você pode simplesmente aninhar tudo (ex, cliente `{_id: 456, nome: 'Restaurante da Praça', endereco: {rua: 'Av Tancredo Neves, 333, sala 14', bairro: 'Centro', cidade: 'Patópolis', uf: 'XY', pais: 'Disney World', cep: '12345-123'} }`).

Nos dois casos (relacional x nosql) há vantagens e desvantagens. Cabe a você analisar fatores tipo: como e com que frequencia esses dados serão acessados e modificados, impacto na performance da aplicação, dificuldade de manutenção dos dados, tamanho dos dados em disco, etc.

Meu conselho tende pro lado do *comece simples, revisite e e aprimore se precisar*.